# How decrease the size of image jpeg/png

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios-simulator

I create an image using the following method by passing the two parameter one is `UIImage` object is imagdata and `NSString` object is storeImage

JPG: `[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageData, 1.0) writeToFile:storeImage atomically:YES];`
or
   PNG:  `[UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageData) writeToFile:storeImage atomically:YES];`

my problem is that, original image size is 2.1 MB after i using the above method the image size is 4.2 MB in simulator.

I don't want to use any compression method and i don't want to loss any quality of image. i want copy the image as it is in given path. in actual size.

Comment: Perhaps `-[NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:];` would be more appropriate?

Comment: If you don't want to lose quality, don't use JPEG.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple data object of your image.Try following code where imageData in NSData object.

> [imageData writeToFile:storeImage atomically:YES];

Answer (score 0):

could you tell me which is the original size and format?
 One way to reduce the size is lose a little of quality.

```
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageData, 0.5) writeToFile:storeImage atomically:YES]
```

Another way could be use ImageIO framework.